# How can I use Window Azure CDN

Tags: azure

I have hosted on web application on window azure platform and now client suggest me to put this video using CDN section but i don't know about how can i do that.

I just go through msdn blogs but not cleared yet that concept, after enabling endpoint how can i put content on CDN and how can i access that content?

can anyone please explain me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already enabled the endpoint for a storage account, then all you need to do is upload your content to a public blob container either [in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800682.aspx) of you can use a one of the [storage](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) [explorers](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloudstoragestudio/).  Then to access the content you can just replace the `myaccount.blob.core.windows.net` part of the url to your blob with `[Default HTTP End Point from the portal].vo.msecnd.net`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straight forward to do, and can be enabled from the Management Console.

Follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Windows Azure Management Console.
2. Go to the CDN option in the menu on the left.
3. Press the 'New Endpoint'.
4. Select the storage account you wish to enable.

There's also a walkthrough here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680301.aspx